# Why I can't see my Window on the plug in area?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I'm not able to see my Window in the plug in area. I know that some code must be added in the `Integrate` section. However i don't know which.

```
public void Integrate() { }

public void IntegratePresentation() {}
```

How can I make it visible? Is it really possible?, if not How can I display a window in Petrel?

Answer (score 3):

You should add your window to the system so that Petrel displays it when requested to.

1. Your window class should be a `ToggleWindow`:

   `public class MyWindow : ToggleWindow{
           ...
   }`
2. Add a menu through which you can ask Petrel to create and open your window in the Windows area:

   ```
   public void IntegratePresentation()
   {
       WellKnownMenus.Window.AddTool(
             new PetrelButtonTool("&My Window", 
                                   PetrelImages.Editor, 
                                   (sender, e) => PetrelProject
                                                  .ToggleWindows
                                                  .Add(new MyWindow())));

   }
   ```

I hope this helps.